# Plotting projectile motion of 1 y-position values vs. 2 x-position values using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, projectile

Hi i'm trying to get  a plot of the trajectory of a mass under projectile motion. One with a force acting on the horizontal axis and one without (basically 2 sets of x values plotted against a 1 set of y-values). Here's what i have so far.. I'm new to programming and i can't seem to figure out where this went wrong. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def position(y0, v0, theta, g, t):
    y= y0 + v0*np.sin(theta)*t + (g*t**2)/2
    return y

def position2(x0, v0, theta, c, e, alpha, t):
    x1 = x0 + v0*(np.cos(theta))*t + c*(t*(e-1)+(2-2*e)/alpha)
    return x1

def position3(x0, v0, theta, t):
    x2 = x0 + v0*(np.cos(theta))*t
    return x2

t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)

#part1
m = 1
theta = 45
y0 = 2
x0 = 0
v0 = 3
k = 1
alpha = 0.5
g = -9.8
c = (-k/m)*(1/alpha**2)
e = -(np.e**(-alpha*t))

x1 = []
x2 = []
y = []

for a in t:
    x1_data = position2(x0, v0, theta, c, e, alpha, t)
    x1.append(x1_data)
    x2_data = position3(x0, v0, theta, t)
    x2.append(x2_data)    
    y_data =  position(y0, v0, theta, g, t)
    y.append(y_data)

print x1_data
print x2_data
print y_data

pl.title('Constant and Time-Dependent Forces')
pl.xlabel(b'x-position')
pl.ylabel(b'y-position')

x1label = 'projectile 1'
x2label = "'normal' projectile"
plot1 = pl.plot(x1_data, y, 'r')
plot2 = pl.plot(x2_data, y, 'b')

pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your code since i am new to `matplotlib` and wanted to play a bit with it. The only mistake i found is in the for loop where you do `for a in t:` but end up passing `t` to the functions instead of `a`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

sin = np.sin
cos = np.cos
pi = np.pi


def y_position(y0, v0, phi, g, t):
    y_t = y0 + v0 * sin(phi) * t + (g * t**2) / 2
    return y_t


def x_position_force(x0, v0, phi, k, m, alpha, t):
    term1 = (-k / m) * (1 / alpha ** 2)
    term2 = -np.e ** (-alpha * t)
    x_t = x0 + v0 * cos(phi) * t + term1 * (t * (term2 - 1) + (2 - 2 * term2) / alpha)
    return x_t


def x_position_no_force(x0, v0, phi, t):
    x_t = x0 + v0 * cos(phi) * t
    return x_t


time = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

#-------------  I N P U T  -------------#
x_init  = 0
y_init  = 2
v_init  = 3
theta   = 45
gravity = -9.8
m = 1
k = 1
alpha = 0.5
#-------------  I N P U T  -------------#
x_with_force = []
x_with_no_force = []
y = []

for time_i in time:
    x_with_force.append(x_position_force(x_init, v_init, theta, k, m, alpha, time_i))
    x_with_no_force.append(x_position_no_force(x_init, v_init, theta, time_i))
    y.append(y_position(y_init, v_init, theta, gravity, time_i))

# print(x1_data)
# print(x2_data)
# print(y_data)

pl.subplot(211)
pl.title('Constant and Time-Dependent Forces')
pl.xlabel('time')
plot1 = pl.plot(time, x_with_force, 'r', label='x_coord_dynamicF')
plot2 = pl.plot(time, x_with_no_force, 'g', label='x_coord_staticF')
plot3 = pl.plot(time, y, 'b', label='y_coord')
pl.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

pl.subplot(212)
pl.title('Trajectory (x,y)')
pl.xlabel('X')
pl.ylabel('Y')
plot4 = pl.plot(x_with_force, y, 'r^')
plot5 = pl.plot(x_with_no_force, y, 'b*')
pl.show()
```

I changed a number of things though to make the code inline with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In my opinion it is the use of bad variable names that lead you to the mistake you did. So i would recommend taking the time to type those few extra characters that ultimately help you and the people reading your code.

Comment: ohhh wow yeah you're right. i got confused with my own variables.. thanks a lot!